# Unexpected U/V plane offset with WIndows Media Foundation H264 decoder

Tags: h.264, ms-media-foundation

While  decoding H264 video via Windows Media Foundation using IMFSourceReader, I am seeing an unexpected y-offset in the U/V plane data. By trial and error, I have found an adjustment that seems to work on all the video sources I've tried, but I'd really like to know if this data layout is expected or documented.

Specifically, sometimes IMFSample::GetTotalLength() returns a total buffer size that is greater than height * stride * 3/2. In that case, the U/V planes are offset from the end of the Y plane data by 2/3 of the extra data, like so:

https://stash.reaper.fm/44192/YV12.png

To be clear, the unexpected part is the N rows of pixels below the Y plane data and above the U plane data. I think all of the other offsets and padding are as expected.  Is this data layout expected or documented?

Image before applying adjustment:

https://stash.reaper.fm/44193/before.jpg

Image after applying adjustment:

https://stash.reaper.fm/44194/after.jpg

The video:

https://stash.reaper.fm/44214/johnny.mp4

Here is a complete program that draws the first frame of the video with and without the adjustment. There is no error checking and the YUV to RGB conversion is very basic.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>

#include "resource.h"

const int marg=16;

unsigned char clamp(int v)
{
  return v < 0 ? 0 : v > 255 ? 255 : v;
}

void yuv_to_rgb(unsigned char *rgb, int y, int u, int v)
{
  y -= 16;
  u -= 128;
  v -= 128;
  rgb[3] = 0;
  rgb[2] = clamp((y*298 + v*409 + 128) / 256);
  rgb[1] = clamp((y*298 - u*100 - v*208 + 128) / 256);
  rgb[0] = clamp((y*298 + u*516 + 128) / 256);
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  static HBITMAP rawbmp = NULL, adjbmp=NULL;
  static unsigned int srcw = 0, srch = 0;

  switch (uMsg)
  {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
      MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

      IMFSourceReader *reader = NULL;
      MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\johnny.mp4", NULL, &reader);
      reader->SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS, FALSE);
      reader->SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, TRUE);

      IMFMediaType *fmt = NULL;
      MFCreateMediaType(&fmt);
      fmt->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
      fmt->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_YV12);
      reader->SetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, NULL, fmt);
      fmt->Release();

      reader->GetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &fmt);
      MFGetAttributeSize(fmt, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &srcw, &srch);
      fmt->Release();

      IMFSample *sample = NULL;
      DWORD flags=0;
      INT64 readpos=0;
      IMFMediaBuffer *buffer = NULL;
      DWORD bufsz=0;
      reader->ReadSample(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, NULL, &flags, &readpos, &sample);
      sample->GetTotalLength(&bufsz);
      sample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&buffer);
      sample->Release();
      reader->Release();

      BITMAPINFO bi = {0};
      bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
      bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = srcw;
      bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = srch;
      bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
      bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
      bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
      unsigned char *raw = NULL, *adj=NULL;
      rawbmp = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&raw, NULL, 0);
      adjbmp = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&adj, NULL, 0);

      IMF2DBuffer *buffer2d = NULL;
      BYTE *bptr = NULL;
      LONG bstride = 0;
      buffer->QueryInterface(&buffer2d);
      buffer2d->Lock2D(&bptr, &bstride);

      int offs=(bufsz*2/3-srch*bstride); // unexpected

      unsigned char *rawptr = raw + srcw*(srch-1)*4;
      unsigned char *adjptr = adj + srcw*(srch-1)*4;
      unsigned char *yptr = bptr;
      unsigned char *uptr = bptr + srch*bstride*5/4;
      unsigned char *vptr = bptr + srch*bstride;

      for (unsigned int y=0; y < srch; ++y)
      {
        for (unsigned int x=0; x < srcw; ++x)
        {
          yuv_to_rgb(rawptr+x*4, yptr[x], uptr[x/2], vptr[x/2]);
          yuv_to_rgb(adjptr+x*4, yptr[x], uptr[x/2+offs], vptr[x/2+offs]);
        }

        rawptr -= srcw*4;
        adjptr -= srcw*4;
        yptr += bstride;
        if (y&1) uptr += bstride/2;
        if (y&1) vptr += bstride/2;
      }

      buffer2d->Unlock2D();
      buffer2d->Release();
      buffer->Release();

      SetWindowPos(hwndDlg, NULL, 0, 0, srcw+2*marg, 2*(srch+2*marg), SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
      DeleteObject(rawbmp);
      DeleteObject(adjbmp);
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
      RECT r;
      GetClientRect(hwndDlg, &r);
      int w=r.right, h=r.bottom;

      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      HDC dc = BeginPaint(hwndDlg, &ps);

      HDC srcdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
      SelectObject(srcdc, rawbmp);
      BitBlt(dc, marg/2, marg/2, srcw, srch, srcdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      SelectObject(srcdc, adjbmp);
      BitBlt(dc, marg/2, (h+marg)/2, srcw, srch, srcdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      EndPaint(hwndDlg, &ps);
      ReleaseDC(hwndDlg, srcdc);
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
      if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
      {
        EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
      }
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), GetDesktopWindow(), wndproc);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The language tag is missing?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include a complete program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please include the language tag, I guess C? or it is c++?

Comment: Also, no need to include the complete code, just the [mre]

Comment: The code is both minimal and complete.

The example code is C++ but the underlying API issue applies to any application that uses the Microsoft media API, including C#, etc. It is a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers."

I believe the question provides all the information necessary for somebody familiar with the context to answer, while also demonstrating an (I think!) undocumented code issue in the Microsoft media API, which may be helpful for somebody else struggling with the same unexpected behavior.